# How to make windows user has access to sql server with integrated security?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, authentication

I have a windows user, e.g. "User1". And I what this User1 to have access to my database.

This code is to create new login and new user in my database:

```
CREATE LOGIN user1
WITH PASSWORD = 'password1';
GO
CREATE USER user1 FOR LOGIN user1;
GO
```

**Edited**  Questions:

1) How to map these two users: "User1" and "user1"?

2) Will this windows user "User1" have access to sql server with integrated security?

Comment: I assume you have no access to it, but Management Studio allows you to do it via GUI

Comment: @Alex, can You explain how to do it via SSMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use master
GO

create login [<YourDomain>\User1] from windows;
GO

use [<YourDatabase>]
GO

create user [<YourDomain>\User1] from login [<YourDomain>\User1]
GO
```

Comment: When I run this code I get "Message 15401: User or the group Windows NT [myDomain\User1] haven't been found. Check the name once again." And I get this message twice: when creating user and login.

Comment: Have you got the login in the right case? Sometimes this is important. Is the account enabled? Are there any other problems with the account?

Comment: As I got it in the 3d line a new windows user is created, right? Can I create a user in my db and map it to the already existing user?

Comment: In the `create login` line, you are creating a login at the server level. Then the script changes context to your database, the second `use` line, and then maps the login previously created to a new user in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Server Management Studio to create the login. [Here is how to do it (MSDN link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx).

TSQL code to accomplish this is also provided in the same page (too long to copy paste here, partial copypaste would be meaningless).

Comment: This is not an answer - it is a link. Links break. -1